# OpenCv for iphone build error

Tags: ios, opencv, namespaces

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ios/video_processing/video_processing.html

I have followed the steps but in the viewController.h file, it tells you to type "using namespace cv;" near the top of the file.

Xcode sees this as an error. And it won't let me build. How do I fix this?

Using XCode 4.6.3 and I can't tell what version of openCV I'm using but I just downloaded, so it's probably the latest. Also, I know that I've imported the opencv framework.

Here are the lines of code in viewController.h:

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import <opencv2/highgui/cap_ios.h>
 using namespace cv;

 @interface ViewController : UIViewController

 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

 - (IBAction)actionStart:(id)sender;
```

@end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the extension of your ViewController from `.m` to `.mm`. That signals to the compiler that you would like to write that piece of code in Objective C++.

Edit: For additional information on how to write code effectively this way, check out [this blog post](http://philjordan.eu/article/strategies-for-using-c++-in-objective-c-projects).

Comment: the source or the header file?

Comment: Only the source file should be mm. Can you try wrapping your using clause in an #ifdef __cplusplus ... #endif block? It might be that ViewController.h is being included in a source file that isn't mm.

Comment: It builds! Thanks! I've noticed that the ViewController.h was being imported into the appDelegate.m file. Was that what was causing the issue?

Comment: Yeah. Clang (the compiler) works on source files that lead to object files. Include files are basically inserted into source files, and since clang has no information about header files after preprocessor directives are taken care of, there's no way for the Objective C++ mish mash to kick in. For that reason we have to wrap the using clause in the ifdef block to avoid a compiler error. The suggestion to make ViewController's source file a `mm` file still stands though.

Comment: By the way, I'd appreciate an upvote/checkmark if this has indeed fixed your problem :)